# how can I use the pdf file from Document folder after that I will give this to the pdf file

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am saving a pdf file in the /Documents/Cachae folder after that I can easily get the path of where my pdf is .. but the problem is that how can I tell the pdfURL toe get the pdf from /Documents folder not the main resource folder

```
pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("newPdf.pdf"), NULL, NULL);

    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    NSLog(@"pdfurl %@",pdfURL);

    CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

any idea about this thing

Answer (score 0):

```
    //---get the path of the Documents folder---
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:"newPdf.pdf"];

pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)filePath);
NSLog(@"pdfurl %@",filePath);

CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

filePath will give you the path to file in the directory.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Sreekumar Kalarikkal , I have done this thing but the problem is that how can I give filePath to pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("newPdf.pdf"), NULL, NULL);

    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    NSLog(@"pdfurl %@",pdfURL);

Comment: substitute pdfURL with filePath

Comment: @SreekumarKalarikkal this will give EXC_BAd_Access in pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)filePath);